# Initializing readonly static field in struct?

Tags: c#, .net, struct, static, readonly

What is the best way to initialize readonly static field in struct? As I know we can initialize readonly field in constructor or right after declaration, but I'm not sure when static constructor will be called or static readonly field will be initialized in struct. For example:

```
public readonly struct Either<T1, T2>
{
    private static readonly StrategyType Strategy =
          Either.IsSmth() ? StrategyType.Strategy1 : StrategyType.Strategy2;

    private readonly object _ref;

    private Either(object @ref)
    {
      _ref = @ref;
    }

    public static implicit operator Either<T1, T2>(T1 value) 
    { 
       if(Strategy == StrategyType.Strategy1) 
          return new Either<T1, T2>();
       // ...code
    }

    public static implicit operator Either<T1, T2>(T2 value) { // ...code }
}
```

or

```
public readonly struct Either<T1, T2>
{
    private static readonly StrategyType Strategy;

    static Either()
    {
      Strategy = Either.IsSmth() ? StrategyType.Strategy1 : StrategyType.Strategy2;
    }

    public static implicit operator Either<T1, T2>(T1 value) { // ...code }

    public static implicit operator Either<T1, T2>(T2 value) { // ...code }
}
```

And usage of this struct:

```
Either<int, string> either = "test";
```

or

```
Either<TestClass1, TestClass2> either = new TestClass1{ TestIntProp = 100 };
```

The code for the field "Strategy" doesn't work and it initializes with default value.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Why not do it in the `// ...code` section, when you create the struct? What you want isn't exactly clear since `IsSmth` is not defined.

Comment: This is a complex topic. The static constructor is more *predictable*, due to "beforefieldinit", but that doesn't necessarily mean "better" - because the whole point of "beforefieldinit" is to prevent unnecessary initializers from running too soon (or possibly ever) - note: it being a struct is not particularly important here - the rules on type initializers are the same for any type

Comment: Rufus L, I want to know the best way to initialize static readonly field in struct, we can set value only in constructor of right after declaration.

Comment: I have updated example and as you see in case when I create new structure with implicity conversion then static readonly field doesn't initialize (not in constructor and not in declaration). So, as I see we have no way to initialize it without workaround, am I right?